# How do I compare dates in one column to a cell in the same row in another column?

Tags: excel, vba

I feel like this should be a simple enough task, but I'm not experienced enough with Excel VBA to know how to approach it.  Basically I want to look at two cells in a row and do something if they both both have specific dates in them.  The two cells will always be in one of two specific columns.

For example, if the date in D2 and I2 both are both earlier than November, then I want to do something to that row and move to the next row.  Then, if the date in D3 and I3 both are both earlier than November, then I want to do something to that row and move to the next row.  And so on, and so on...

My problem isn't so much about how to do all the steps.  It's really about how to go about doing this compare.  I know how to select just the cells in those two columns by doing the following:

```vb
Union(Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)), _
    Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))).Select
```

But then it occurred to me that I don't know how I would go about comparing the respective cells of both columns.  I only know how to loop through each cell of *one* column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just looping through 1 column, then using the `Offset` method to compare.

Check this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckTwoCols()

Dim wks As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, rng As Range, cel as Range

Set wks = Sheets(1) 'change sheet reference to suit your needs

With wks

    lastrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row

    Set rng = .Range("D2:D" & lastrow)

    For each cel in rng

        'column I is 5 columns to the right of column D
        If cel < "11/1/2012" and cel.offset(,5)  < "11/1/2012" Then

             'process code

        End If 

   Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: some comments for improvement: always use `Range.Value` and better even `Value2` in your code. 11/1/2012 isnt a date for VBA it is 11 divided by 1 divided by 2012 which is 11/2012th... There are some interesting assumptions in your code (why `Sheets(1)`?). The naming of variables isnt very explanatory (`rng` and `cel`), especially if there is some more code in the `'process code` bit

Comment: Thank you, Scott, I knew there was a simpler approach to it, but I forgot about going by the offset.

@K_B, you're correct Scott's code isn't perfect, but I was looking for more of an idea than a perfect execution, so it's good for me.  Hopefully, someone else looking at this will see your comment.

Comment: @K_B - thanks for the comment. As Mike said, I wrote this just as a concept, so that's why it was a bit patchwork. However, since it's bad practice to write bad code, I've made some edits to improve someone else who may look at the answer.